# Explanation of $\sum_{k}[x^k]f(x)g(y)^k=f(g(y))$

Tags: summation, algorithms, proof-explanation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

In the book "Mathematics for the Analysis of Algorithms" by Daniel H. Greene and Donald E. Knuth, they cover the example,
$$S=\sum_{k}\binom{m}{k}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\binom{2k}{k}$$
After expressing portions of the sum with generating functions, they make the transformation,

$$\begin{align*} S &= \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^m\sum_k[x^k] (1-2x)^m [y^{m-k}] (1+y)^{2m-2k} \\
&= \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^m [y^m] (1+y)^{2m}\sum_k [x^k] (1-2x)^m \left(\frac{y}{(1+y)^2}\right)^k\end{align*}$$

after noticing that $[y^{m-k}]=[y^m]y^k$, where $[x^n]f(x)$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $f(x)$. Then, the solution follows immediately as,
$$\sum_{k}[x^k]f(x)g(y)^k=f(g(y))$$
when $f$ is analytic.
$$S = (-2)^{-m} [y^m] (1+y)^{2m}\left(1-\frac{2y}{(1+y)^2}\right)^m=(-2)^{-m} [y^m] (1+y^2)^m$$
$$S= \begin{cases}
2^{-m}\binom{m}{m/2},& m\ \text{even} \\
0,& m\ \text{odd}.
 \end{cases}$$

---

I do not understand the formula,
$$\sum_{k}[x^k]f(x)g(y)^k=f(g(y))$$
and can't seem to find any explanation for it in the book. Can someone explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is a typo and the formula should be $\sum_{k}[x^k]f(x)g(y)^k=f(g(y))$? It is somehow obvious from that.

Comment: You are right. I've corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of zero with: $$f(x)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N_0}a_nx^n$$
And $g(y)$ is sufficiently close to zero then: $$\sum_{k\in\Bbb N_0}[x^k]f(x)g(y)^k=\sum_{k\in\Bbb N_0}a_kg(y)^k=f(g(y))$$

Follows quickly. Here: $$f(x):=(1-2x)^m$$Is analytic with infinite radius of convergence (if $m\ge0$ is an integer) so $g(y)=\frac{y}{(1+y)^2}$ is always sufficiently close to zero as to make $\sum_k a_kg(y)^k$ make sense.